# Ruby does not 'ensure' when I 'retry' in 'rescue'

Tags: ruby, rescue

Consider this begin-rescue-ensure block:

```
attempts=0
begin
  make_service_call()
rescue Exception
  retry unless attempts>2
  exit -1
ensure
  attemps += 1
end
```

If you run that code as it is, it raises an exception because there is no function called 'make_service_call()'. So, it retries. But it would be stuck in infinite loop because the control never goes to 'ensure' because of the 'retry'. Shouldn't 'ensure' part of the block ensure that the code in it gets executed no matter what happens in 'begin' or 'rescue'?

Of course I can increment the count in 'begin' - that's not the point. I am just asking the question about 'ensure' to get some clarity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `ensure` section is executed when leaving the `begin` statement (by any means) but when you `retry`, you're just moving around inside the statement so the ensure section will not be executed.

Try this version of your example to get a better idea of what's going on:

```
attempts = 0
begin
  make_service_call()
rescue Exception
  attempts += 1
  retry unless attempts > 2
  exit -1
ensure
  puts "ensure! #{attempts}"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`ensure` code is executed once, just before the code block exits and it *will* be called at that time.

But because of the `unless attempts>2` condition, and the fact that `ensure` will only be called "just before the code exits" (e.g. due to `exit -1`) the `attempts += 1` will not be executed, and so there is an infinite loop.

`ensure` is like `__finally` in C++ : you could `catch` the exception and then use a `goto` : but `finally` will not be called until the function is actually about to exit.